# Plotting error bars around longitudinal dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some error bars to a very large longitudinal data. Since its very uninformative to plot the entire dataset, I just want a plot that shows the mean and error margins or even confidence intervals rather than the whole dataset. I was working through the [R cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/) section on error bars but I'm having difficulty adapting this code to longitudinal data.

For reproducibility, I've been trying to use the `Theoph` dataset. I'm a bit stuck at this stage (summarySE is a function from the R Cookbook website):

```
tp <- summarySE(Theoph, measurevar = c("conc"), 
            groupvars = c("Subject", "Wt", "Dose"))
```

Here's the Theoph data (conc. against time):

[image: Theoph data (conc vs time)]

Here's an example of a plot that I would like to obtain:

[image: error bars]

Can anyone help in modifying the code from the R Cookbook so I can plot concentration against time? Alternatively, any other new approaches is kindly welcome.

Comment: you only have single measurements at each time, so there is no error right

Comment: Yes, you're right-single measurements for each time point/per subject but I'd like to have an idea of the spread of the data-hence I need the overall mean and something to show deviation from this mean.

Comment: do you want a plot with one line (no grouping by subjects) with error bars?

Comment: Yes-precisely! Thanks.

Comment: O nevermind, I thought Time was categorical, its continuous.  You could break it into bins, or just use `geom_smooth` to fit a curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the idea, but that's going to be tricky. See, you cannot use `summarySE` as you demonstrate since it destroys the `Time` variable. We could add it to `groupvars` if it was categorical (as @LegalizeIt says), but it is not.

Here's an example of using `geom_smooth`. Note that `aes(group = Subject)` is only set for `geom_line`, not `geom_smooth`. I also removed colors to make the plot less distracting.

```
ggplot(Theoph, aes(Time, conc)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = Subject), alpha = 0.4) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4) + 
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems its not very easy to get these sort of plots for longitudinal dataset.